Why can methods return references with the lifetime of &self, when &self does not exist after the function call
In the code below, rand_elt(&self) returns a & String and both of them have the same generic lifetime 'a. However, the &self will only be alive during the duration of the rand_elt() call, but the references &String is returned and moved out. Initially I was a bit confused, why they still both can have the same generic lifetime 'a.
In "Rust for Rustaceans", Jon Gjengset describes references as "a lifetime is really a region of code some references must be valid for".
I wonder whether this sentence should instead be phrased: "a lifetime is really a region of code some references could be valid for". I.e. the references that are being talked about do not necessarily exist in the code: when printing x1, the variable self from the rand_elt() function of course does not exist anymore, but it would be possible to create a variable &a, as no other mutable reference exists.
My question is basically: Is this understanding correct or am I missing something here?
pub struct A {
    pub vals: Vec<String>,
}

impl A {
    fn rand_elt<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a String {
        use rand::prelude::*;
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        let i: usize = rng.gen_range(0..self.vals.len()); //
        &self.vals[i]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = A {
        vals: vec!["x".to_string(), "y".to_string(), "z".to_string()],
    };

    let x1 = a.rand_elt();
    let x2 = a.rand_elt();
    println!("{}", x1);
    println!("{}", x2);
}


The lifetime is 'a is passed in from the outside so self is valid for longer than the body of the function (by another name, but still) how long exactly is determined by the code that calls rand_elt.

I think my argument still holds though: where is &self created in the code that calls rand_elt()? it is never bound to a variable, right?

and yes, self is valid for longer, but the lifetime 'a is with respect to &self, and not self.

self has type &'a Self the reference is created in the method call, and taken to be as long as the output, because you (or the compiler implicitly) connected the lifetimes.

@Sebastian no 'a is not with respect to &self, it's the expression of a relationship / constraint between &self and self. 'a is a span for which self must be alive / valid.

So in your snippet, it means that a must remain alive for as long as x1 and x2 are alive, or that x1 and x2 can't outlive a. For that reason if you try to drop a before the printlns which need references, thus a live a) you'll get a compilation error. Similarly if you try to make the references escape.

As mentioned in the comments, a lifetime seen in &'a T is not restricted to the life of the reference itself.
Lifetimes are more of a concept than a tangible thing like references are. References are data types and thus follow the rules as any other: e.g. they are subject to drop rules and temporary scopes like you've already hinted (though since they are Copy that doesn't mean much). In contrast, lifetimes are a less defined idea that you as a user don't define explicitly (beyond 'static) and instead only manipulate through associations and constraints.
In your rand_elt method, you've made the association that the returned &String is linked to &self. When the compiler runs borrow checking analysis for your program, it looks at these associations and forms "regions" for these lifetimes. In simple terms, the compiler will prefer the smallest regions possible to best avoid conflicts (see non-lexical lifetimes). So when determining the 'a lifetime for &self when calling a.rand_elt() the first time, it not only looks at the temporary reference created, but also the &String that gets returned. It then assesses how long that reference needs to be accessible for (here at the println! below) and thus forms that as the lifetime 'a to be used in the call. If there were more references spawned from x1/x2, then 'a would be expanded to encompass those as well.
Here is a simple diagram for the deduced lifetimes (it is not always this clear):
fn main() {
    let a = A {
        vals: vec!["x".to_string(), "y".to_string(), "z".to_string()],
    };

    let x1 = a.rand_elt(); // ---+ 'x1
    let x2 = a.rand_elt(); // ---|-+ 'x2
                           //    | |
    println!("{}", x1);    // ---+ |
    println!("{}", x2);    // -----+
}

So to address the wording between "a region of code some references must be valid for" vs "a region of code some references could be valid for", both can be correct depending how you look at them. The first one from Jon Gjengset is to inform that references must stay valid meaning the reference cannot refer to an object beyond its lifetime (no dangling references). And I see your point about the second wording, i.e. the reference itself may not live for that whole lifetime, but also its not quite right because it could live for that whole lifetime (e.g. its the only reference with that lifetime).
All in all, I think your understanding is correct. But I hope some added perspective helps you see these concepts a bit differently.

I think the point that you're missing is that the method's receiver, &'a self, doesn't belong only to rand_elt – it's provided by the calling function main, meaning that the reference that rand_elt calls self (and, in this example, that main calls &a) is still valid even after rand_elt returns.
Because the return value is being returned to the caller – which provided the reference in the first place – the caller is able to keep the reference that it gave as the method's receiver alive for as long as it is using the return value (which is specified in rand_elt's signature by giving them both the same lifetime). So in effect, rand_elt is delegating the requirement to keep the references alive for long enough to its caller.
It's easy enough to get a demonstration of this by trying to mutate a from within main:
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { // `mut` so that we can change it later
        vals: vec!["x".to_string(), "y".to_string(), "z".to_string()],
    };

    let x1 = a.rand_elt();
    let x2 = a.rand_elt();

    a.vals[0] = "q".to_string(); // I added this line

    println!("{}", x1);
    println!("{}", x2);
}

This causes the compiler to complain that a is still borrowed:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a.vals` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
19 |     let x1 = a.rand_elt();
   |              - immutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |     a.vals[0] = "q".to_string();
   |     ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
23 |
24 |     println!("{}", x1);
   |                    -- immutable borrow later used here

because main has to keep its borrow of a – i.e. rand_elt's self argument – alive for as long as x1 is alive.
